# Phonegap: navigating through directories, index position is incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to navigate through my music directory using a click event - I can get the original listview showing up ok to begin with, the click event will drill down to the next directory, but on the third click my index position keeps returning the fullPath of the original directoryentry object.

JS

```
    function readerSuccess(entries) {
    $("#test").empty();
    for (i=0;i<entries.length;i++){


    $("#test").append("<li>"+entries[i].name+"</li>");


    }

    $("#test").listview("refresh");


    ListClickHandler(entries);
    }






var ListClickHandler = function(something){
    $(document).on("click","#test li",function(event){
    var mylistname = $(this).text();

    var index = $("#test li").index(this);

    var listpath = something[index].fullPath; //this is causing the problem. entries never changes.
    alert(index);

        if(something[index].isFile ===true)
            {
            $("#test").empty();
            alert("this is a file");
            }

            else if(something[index].isDirectory===true)
            {

            var directoryentry = new DirectoryEntry(mylistname,listpath);
            var directoryreader = directoryentry.createReader();
            directoryreader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);
            //alert("this is a directory"+mylistname+listpath);
            }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the following code. Im sure its a bit of mess but hopefully will help someone out if they are stumped on the same issue. Basically this will start off by reading the first directories in my music root folder, then when each list directory item is clicked it will refresh with the subdirectories, files etc.

I had to move the $(document),on("click" .....) into the readerSuccess function so it was picking up the correct list entry when the list click event was fired. I also added two new arrays to contain entries.name and entries.fullPath which get emptied on each iteration and repopulated with the correct data. The following code is how i got it to work but im sure there is a better way out there. I couldn't find anything after googling hopelessly.

```
function readerSuccess(entries) {
    $("#test").empty();
    var listnames = new Array();
    var listpositions = new Array();

    for (i=0;i<entries.length;i++){
    if (entries[i].isDirectory===true)
    {
    alert("this is a directory");
    }
    if (entries[i].isFile===true){
    alert("this is a file")
    }

    $("#test").append("<li>"+entries[i].name+"</li>");

    listnames.push(entries[i].name);
    listpositions.push(entries[i].fullPath);

    }

    $("#test").listview("refresh");
        $(document).on("click","#test li",function(event){
    var mylistname = $(this).text();
    //alert(mylistname);
    var index = $("#test li").index(this);
    //alert(index);
    var listpath = listpositions[index];
    //alert(listpath);
    listnames.length=0;     //resets the array so new data appends with correct pos
    listpositions.length=0; //resets the array so new data appends with correct pos
    var directoryentry= new DirectoryEntry(mylistname,listpath);
    var directoryreader = directoryentry.createReader();

    directoryreader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);


    });
```